# Android findViewById(), getComponentName() and getSystemService(): Cannot make a static reference to a nonstatic field from type Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, compiler-errors

In the following class, I am getting the following three compiler errors in the `enableAssistedSearch` method.

- Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method
  `getSystemService(String)` from the type `Activity`
- Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method
  `getComponentName()` from the type `Activity`
- Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method
  `findViewById(int)` from the type `Activity`

I am using the `Eclipse`, and "cleaning the project" did not help.

Also, the class also contains another `findViewById` call, but that does not raise any error, which is quite bewildering.

```
package practiceTests.test2.assistedSearchUsingSearchWidget;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.app.SearchableInfo;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SearchActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.searchActivity_textView);

        enableAssistedSearch();

        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }


    /**
     * 
     */
    private static void enableAssistedSearch() {
        // SearchManager => provides access to the system search services.
        // Context.getSystemService() => Return the handle to a system-level
        // service by name. The class of the returned object varies by the
        // requested name.
        // Context.SEARCH_SERVICE => Returns a SearchManager for handling search
        // Context = Interface to global information about an application
        // environment. This is an abstract class whose implementation is
        // provided by the Android system. It allows access to
        // application-specific resources and classes, as well as up-calls for
        // application-level operations such as launching activities,
        // broadcasting and receiving intents, etc.
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);//**************************
        //getSearchableInfo() => gets information about a searchable activity. @return => the activity to get searchable information for.
        SearchableInfo searchableInfo = searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());//**************************

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);//**************************
    }


    /**
     * 
     */
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }


    /**
     * 
     */
    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH)) {
            performSearch(intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY));
        }
    }


    /**
     * 
     */
    private void performSearch(String searchQuery) {
        textView.setText(searchQuery);
    }

}
```

I couldn't figure out why! So can anybody point out any problems, or suggest what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it because your method is `static` and it doen't allow the access to the object instance itself, and since `findViewById` is method of `Activity`, but you can't access the instance itself, you get this compile time error, and so on for the other errors

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem. I have already started reading the basic Java tutorials to fix these concepts. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you declared:

> private **static** void enableAssistedSearch()

you should try to remove the word "static"

getSystemService(String), getComponentName(), findViewById(int) are defined as the member methods inherited from the super class Activity (or even the base class Context). A member method is part of the object instance, it insists to handle something of itself and implies to be called after the object instance is being created.

Static methods allow to be called even before creating any object instance, in the static scope. During that time, you can assume there is no Activity instance exists and thus those 3 member methods won't able to be called.

Please note that you don't usually create the new instance of Activity, but android sdk does it.